# Calling recvmsg manually from .NET Core on Linux doesn't return

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, .net-core

I'm writing a DBus client for .NET Core [here](https://github.com/Tragetaschen/DbusCore). For some features (for example systemd's inhibitor locks), there's a need to receive file descriptors over the Unix socket connection and those require the control-related messages that `recvmsg` puts in the `struct msghdr`. .NETs socket API doesn't give me access to that function (or an abstraction), so I have to call it manually.

The guts of the code leading to my very first `recvmsg` call is [here](https://github.com/Tragetaschen/DbusCore/blob/master/src/Dbus/Connection.Receive.cs#L53). When I compile it against net462 and run it via Mono 5.0.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 box or Yocto distribution (also with Mono), everything works as expected.

The problem starts when I compile it against netcoreapp1.1/netstandard1.6 and run it with `dotnet`: The `recvmsg` call just doesn't return for the first `Hello` call against `org.freedesktop.DBus`.

I can see with `dbus-monitor --system` that the method call has left my application and that DBus sent the method return as well as `NameOwnerChanged` and `NameAcquired` signals.

A couple of notes:

- For my tests on Ubuntu, I have changed the `size_t` fields in `iovec` and `msghdr` from `int` to `long` to actually be 64-bit (although it looks like the required alignment for the structs made it work anyway)
- The actual `ConnectAsync` call on the socket is slightly different: For net462 I've copied the [extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.1.0/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/SocketTaskExtensions.cs#L31) from .NET Core 1.1
- To get my hands on the native socket handle, I can use the Handle property on net462, but [resort to reflecting the private field](https://github.com/Tragetaschen/DbusCore/blob/master/src/Dbus/Connection.cs#L67) in the netcoreapp1.1 build.
- I have also checked against the .NET Core 2.0 preview2 builds and those behave exactly like .NET Core 1.1
- Calling `Read` on the socket instead of `recvmsg` works, although Read internally just maps down to `recvmsg`
- I have compared the public properties on the Socket between Mono and .NET Core with no obvious differences: Accessing ExclusiveAddressUse works on Mono, but throws on .NET Core.
- There's a bit of authentication code [here](https://github.com/Tragetaschen/DbusCore/blob/master/src/Dbus/Connection.Authentication.cs#L11) before the receive thread starts its work. This does some TPL-based reading from the socket.

I've tried to walk through the CoreFX Socket code, but this isn't exactly fun due to the complexities involved.

What's the missing link?

Answer (score 1):

There have been two successive issues.

First, my receive method successfully swallowed an exception that could have been visible if I had ran the Connection's Dispose method instead of CTRL+C'ing out of the program.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Cannot marshal field 'control' of type 'msghdr': Unknown error.
   at System.StubHelpers.ValueClassMarshaler.ConvertToNative(IntPtr dst, IntPtr src, IntPtr pMT, CleanupWorkList& pCleanupWorkList)
   at Dbus.Connection.recvmsg(IntPtr sockfd, msghdr& buf, Int32 flags)
   at Dbus.Connection.receive()
```

So the `recvmsg` was never actually called. The reason is that the `control` field was typed `int[]`. I changed that to `int*` and added another `fixed`.

It's strange, though, that Mono is capable of marshaling this struct with an `int[]` field and .NET Core isn't.

After that, `recvmsg` was actually called, but returned -1 immediately. Still, if I would just `Read` using the .NET socket, everything worked fine. I have opted to run the entire socket handling through the libc API directly and don't use the .NET Core Socket type anymore. Now, `recvmsg` works as expected. I'm assuming my TPL based DBus authorization left the socket with an active read and my receive method was performing a second read that was "blocked", but I haven't verified that hypothesis.